# Folders and files not showing in CVS Synchronize with Repository view in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cvs

Going to the CVS repository perspective and viewing the files shows them, so they checked in just fine, and doing an update will bring them into the project. It is only the synchronize that is having problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have noticed that, when synchronizing trees that do not contain source files such as *.java files causes the cvs synchronize view to look strange (there is an update to be done but it cannot specify the path). Usually, you would actually want to see what is updated..

So, the solution as per me is to perform a team->update on project root level, or to use another cvs client to make the update. (TortoiseCvs works)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the problem, but do you realize files won't appear in the synchronize view if they are identical to the files in the repository?

Comment: Yeah, they're not -- they are newly created :)